# Calling a webservice through jquery cross domain

Tags: web-services, jquery, cross-domain

I am trying to connect to a .asmx webservice (cross domain) by means of client-side script  now actually i am having problems to use POST since it is being blocked and in firebug is giving me:

OPTIONS Add(method name) 500 internal server error.

I bypassed this problem by using GET instead, it is working fine when not inputting any parameters but is giving me trouble with parameters. please see below for the code.

The following is a simple example I am trying to make work out with the use of parameters.

### With Parameters

```
function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:2968/MyService.asmx/Add",
            data: "{'num1':'" + $("#txtValue1").val() + "','num2':'" + $("#txtValue2").val() + "'}",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data.d);
            }

        });
```

### Webservice

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return (num1 + num2).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What response do you see in firebug when adding parameters?  Or does it not get that far?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException"
this is how the link is getting:
http://localhost:2968/MyService.asmx/Add?callback=jsonp1273315927276&=1273315935180&{%27num1%27:%2722%27,%27num2%27:%2722%27}

Comment: The odd thing and which I don't like most is that I cannot make POST

Comment: That's the preferred method, can you see what the 500 error is in firebug or the event log when you POST?

Comment: All I can get is the Response Header and the Request Header:
Response Header
--------
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date: Sat, 08 May 2010 11:47:10 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
jsonerror: true
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 416
Connection: Close

Comment: Request Header:<br/>
Host localhost:2968
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 115
Connection keep-alive
Origin http://localhost:3078
Access-Control-Request-Me... POST
Access-Control-Request-He... x-requested-with

Comment: Can you look at the event log to see the actual error?

Comment: where can i see the event log in firebug? or the one in administritive tools ?  the one in administritive tools is not giving any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attempt to resolve the error on the service - if the WSDL says that you should be able to POST a request and you are passing the correct request, it shouldn't error and that is for the service provider to fix. It is entirely possible that the error they are returning is related to you sending invalid parameters, so check that your request is spot on before referring to the service provider.

They can look at their error logs, or indeed their event viewer to find the exact error message, which may not be made public for security reasons.