# jQuery ASP.Net Webforms AJAX

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms

I have a standalone webform (no masterpage) that opens in a div from another page. The standalone page uses jquery to move a user through a non-linear questionnaire. At the end of the questionnaire there is a result displayed with a "complete" button. When the user hits the complete button the result is sent back to the parent/host page of the div.

I have a new requirement where i need to actually pass the question and answer id's to code-behind or web service where i can insert the question and answer id's to my DB.

None of what i need to do requires object serialization. I want to do this as simply as possible.. none of the controls in the questionnaire are server controls.. just regular select boxes or radio button groups. I suppose i could do an ajax postback using an update panel or something but not sure if making the controls runat=server will screw up all the jquery/js i have working in the questionnaire.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tackle this by using jQuery to post the data to a web service, which is fairly trivial.  There's are a couple of code examples for doing this with asp.net here:

[jQuery: Ajax call to asp.net webservice fails, server return 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027960/jquery-ajax-call-to-asp-net-webservice-fails-server-return-500-error)

and

[Calling a webservice through jquery cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793836/calling-a-webservice-through-jquery-cross-domain)

To answer your other question, putting runat="server" will not have an affect of jQuery's ability to parse the elements in the DOM.